# is there a way to make the x odd

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a simple code with python in which it takes an input '**n**' and outputs the numbers from 1 to **n**
for each multiple of 3, print **Solo** instead of the number
for each multiple of 5, print **Learn** instead of the number
for numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5, output **SoloLearn**
I want to code it in a way that the logic will skip the even numbers and can only be applied to odd numbers in the range

**this is my code below**

```
n = int(input())
for x in range(1, n):
    if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
        print("SoloLearn")    
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        print("Solo")
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        print("Learn")
    else:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Just change `range(1, n)` to `range(1, n, 2)` to skip the even numbers.  Note that both of these will skip `n`, so if you want to include `n`, change it to `n+1`.

Comment: @TomKarzes I had not read this comment when I wrote my answer - this is the simplest approach (and what I independently replicated)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `continue` clause at the top of your loop:

```py
if x % 2 == 0:
    continue
```

For more details, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest/fastest/smallest amount of changes you need to make is to just alter the range function to give you exactly what you want.

```py
n = int(input())
for x in range(1, n + 1 , 2):
    if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
        print("SoloLearn")    
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        print("Solo")
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        print("Learn")
    else:
        print(x)
```

I added n+1 not to satisfy your question, but because I think as written your code was not correct -> for example run these two snippets and see what I mean. If you didn't want n to be part of the range than your code is correct without the `n+1`.

```
print("no +1")
for i in range(1,11,2):
    print(i)
print("\n\nwith + 1"
for i in range(1,11+1,1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the 'for' loop to 'while' loop . Since we are starting with 1 , adding 2 in each iteration , makes the loop run only for odd numbers.

```
n = int(input())
x=1

while x<n:
    if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
        print(x ,"SoloLearn")    
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        print(x, "Solo")
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        print(x, "Learn")
    else:
        print(x)
    x=x+2
```